# Search Directories for ld passed via gcc and loaded libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

I am trying to crosscompile a simple c program using gcc. In my case it is a small gtk2 application:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to link it against gtk-x11-2.0, which contains the gtk_init function. When passing via -L he explicit path to the rootsys of the remote system and analyzing the output of the linker via

```
gcc ... -Wl,-verbose ... ,
```

I can see that the path is not listed as

```
SEARCH_DIR("= ...")
```

and results in a "undefined reference to gtk_init..."
but in the end of the output it shows that the library has been loaded at the right path.
See complete linker script listing:

```
16:01:37 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project 

SysrootTest ****
make all 
#arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v -g -Wall  -mtune=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a  --sysroot=/home/dominik/bbbroot -o simple -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Xlinker -rpath-link=/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include -lgtk-x11-2.0 simple.c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v -g -Wall  -mtune=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a  --sysroot=/home/dominik/bbbroot -o simple -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Xlinker -rpath-link=/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-verbose,-L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include -lgtk-x11-2.0 simple.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-16ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf-cross/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf-cross --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-armhf-cross --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libgcj --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-16ubuntu4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-Wall' '-mtune=cortex-a8' '-march=armv7-a' '-o' 'simple' '-L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include' '-shared-libgcc' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf -isysroot /home/dominik/bbbroot -D_GNU_SOURCE simple.c -quiet -dumpbase simple.c -mtune=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mthumb -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase simple -g -Wall -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccjGniT3.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-16ubuntu4) version 4.8.2 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.2-16ubuntu4) version 4.8.2 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 5864e76821369f09a9f341580a4c0155
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-Wall' '-mtune=cortex-a8' '-march=armv7-a' '-o' 'simple' '-L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include' '-shared-libgcc' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/as -v -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -meabi=5 -o /tmp/cc4sA1i3.o /tmp/ccjGniT3.s
Die GNU-Assembler-Version 2.24 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) benutzt die BFD-Version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/:/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/../lib/:/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/:/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/:/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-Wall' '-mtune=cortex-a8' '-march=armv7-a' '-o' 'simple' '-L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gtk-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/pango-1.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/atk-1.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/include/glib-2.0' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include' '-I' '/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include' '-shared-libgcc' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' '-mthumb' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/home/dominik/bbbroot --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -X --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -m armelf_linux_eabi -z relro -o simple /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/../lib -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib -rpath-link=/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -verbose -L/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lgtk-x11-2.0 /tmp/cc4sA1i3.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
  Unterstützte Emulationen:
   armelf_linux_eabi
   armelfb_linux_eabi
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-bigarm",
          "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(_start)
/tmp/cc4sA1i3.o: In Funktion `main':
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib");
/home/dominik/workspaces/Mars/Beaglebone/SysrootTest//simple.c:23: Nicht definierter Verweis auf `gtk_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
SECTIONS
make: *** [main] Fehler 1
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x00008000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x00008000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rel.dyn        :
    {
      *(.rel.init)
      *(.rel.text .rel.text.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rel.fini)
      *(.rel.rodata .rel.rodata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rel.data.rel.ro .rel.data.rel.ro.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*)
      *(.rel.data .rel.data.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rel.tdata .rel.tdata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rel.tbss .rel.tbss.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rel.ctors)
      *(.rel.dtors)
      *(.rel.got)
      *(.rel.bss .rel.bss.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rel_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rel.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rel_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .rel.plt        :
    {
      *(.rel.plt)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) }
  .iplt           : { *(.iplt) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
    *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7) *(.vfp11_veneer) *(.v4_bx)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) }
   PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
  .ARM.exidx   : { *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*) }
   PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)); . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array ))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array ))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (0, .);
  .got            : { *(.got.plt) *(.igot.plt) *(.got) *(.igot) }
  .data           :
  {
    PROVIDE (__data_start = .);
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  __bss_start__ = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 32 / 8 : 1);
  }
  _bss_end__ = . ; __bss_end__ = . ;
  . = ALIGN(32 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  . = ALIGN(32 / 8);
  __end__ = . ;
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  .note.gnu.arm.ident 0 : { KEEP (*(.note.gnu.arm.ident)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crt1.o zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crt1.o
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crti.o zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crti.o
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/crtbegin.o zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/crtbegin.o
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
-lgtk-x11-2.0 (/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so)
Der Versuch, /tmp/cc4sA1i3.o zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/tmp/cc4sA1i3.o
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libstdc++.so zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
-lstdc++ (/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libstdc++.so)
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
-lm (/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so)
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Skriptdatei /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so geöffnet
Skriptdatei /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so geöffnet
Der Versuch, libgcc_s.so.1 zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so.1 zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so.1)
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.a zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.a zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Skriptdatei /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so geöffnet
Skriptdatei /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so geöffnet
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6)
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
(/home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (/home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3)
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Skriptdatei /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so geöffnet
Skriptdatei /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so geöffnet
Der Versuch, libgcc_s.so.1 zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so.1 zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
libgcc_s.so.1 (/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc_s.so.1)
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.a zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /home/dominik/bbbroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc.a zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.so zu öffnen, ist fehlgeschlagen
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/libgcc.a zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/crtend.o zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/crtend.o
Der Versuch, /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crtn.o zu öffnen, war erfolgreich
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/crtn.o
ld-linux-armhf.so.3 needed by /home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-armhf.so.3 at /home/dominik/bbbroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

16:01:40 Build Finished (took 2s.415ms)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check that library "gtk-x11-2.0" exists. If it does then try to include the library folder using option -L

Comment: Thank you StahlRat, "gtk-x11-2.0" does exist. I now checked to run the compiler first and than run the linker seperately. In that case it does work. I still have no clue why it fails when piping the ld through g++